# Finding $(a,b,n)~$ such that $~5^{a}43^{b}+1=n^{3}$ ($a$,$b$,$n$ $\in N$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To everyone.

Find $(a,b,n)~$ such that $~5^{a}43^{b}+1=n^{3}$ ($a$,$b$,$n$ $\in N$)

The part of my solution is the following.

$5^{a}43^{b}=n^{3}-1=(n-1)(n^{2}+n+1)$

$gcd(n-1,n^{2}+n+1)=1$, $3$ $~\Longrightarrow~$ $gcd(n-1,n^{2}+n+1)=1$

case (1) : $~n-1=5^{a}$, $~n^{2}+n+1=43^{b}$

case (2) : $~n-1=43^{b}$, $~n^{2}+n+1=5^{a}$

From here, I can't proceed anymore and ask some help for you.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for clarification, do you need to find one such triplet or all of them?

Comment: I found only one (1,1,6) but can't find anymore...

Comment: @BrunoB FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%245%5E%7Ba%7D43%5E%7Bb%7D%2B1%3Dn%5E3%24&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [Find l,m,n that satisfy the equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1703031p10949980), where the solution in [Post #$7$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1703031p20110105), which I've briefly checked with it appearing to be correct, shows there's just one solution (with it being what the OP also has found in their comment above).